# What to do when NuGet doesn't have the latest updates?

Tags: c#, nuget

My project has a dependency on a certain NuGet package ([Jint](https://github.com/sebastienros/jint), to be specific). A bugfix was committed to the trunk of that project a couple of months ago that I need to have in my project, but an update hasn't been pushed to NuGet.org yet.

What are some best practices in dealing with this situation?

Things I've considered:

1. Pull down the source and put it directly into my project. I don't really want to do this because it's going to pollute my repo with the source of some other project.
2. Build the source and hard link the .dll into my project, maybe putting the .dll in the repo. Seems sort of okay, but I don't typically like to check binaries into my source control.
3. Build the source, package into a NuGet package and post it to a private NuGet feed. This seems like the least-worst solution, but a big pain.

If anyone has successfully dealt with this scenario before, I'd love to hear what your approach was.

Comment: Have you tried asking the authors to publish the changes to NuGet? They might be willing to do so if they know someone's waiting for it.

Comment: As an owner of several packages that I don't author I definitely agree with contacting them. If I'm not using the package any more in a current project I don't update it until someone asks. Also, once they ask I usually offer to hand over ownership since they're clearly more invested than I, so be prepared for that :) That being said, I take great care to set up packages so that they're dirt simple to update and verify.

Comment: These are both good comments. It's funny this didn't cross my mind - I'm a typical engineer and I don't like talking to people! :D I will give this a shot, but I'm still interested in possible solutions for scenarios where this doesn't or can't work.